# Drag and drop Outlook mail in windows Gadget

Tags: outlook, drag-and-drop

I drag mail message or mail message attachment from Outlook.
What types parameter data put outlook in [`dataTransfer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

When drop is done in call function

```cs
function GetItemFromDrop() {
    var t1 = event.dataTransfer.files;
    var t2 = event.dataTransfer.types;
    var t3 = event.dataTransfer.items;
    var t4 = System.Shell.itemFromFileDrop(event.dataTransfer, intIndex);
}
```

In result: `t1=t2=t3=t4=null`

When dragging file from file system, all worked.

Answer (score 0):

`CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR` and `CF_FILECONTENTS` formats.

See [Upload fails when user drags and drops attachment from email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachement-from-email-client/17197224#17197224)